# Argument 1 passed to Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\BlockInteractor::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

After composer update i get new errors

```
Argument 1 passed to Sonata\PageBundle\Entity\BlockInteractor::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given,
```

symfony config

```
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.48",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.9",
    "sonata-project/page-bundle": "^3.11",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "^2.4",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^4.3",
    "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue shows when auto update doctrine-bundle (to  "version": "2.0.2" )

```
 "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.12.2",
```

This work.

Here are more pieces of information https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29810

Answer (score 0):

not sure but try extends AsbtractController instead of Controller  and use dependancy injection, i had similar problem with bundle for pagination

```
 //the use for my example
use Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface; 


public function recap(Request $request, PaginatorInterface $paginator)
```

, maybe it's that